# Using VLC's hot keys via the command line

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player

`vlc --help` lists, among other content, command line options like the following:

```
 Hot keys
      --global-key-toggle-fullscreen <string>
                                 Fullscreen
      --key-toggle-fullscreen <string>
                                 Fullscreen
      --global-key-leave-fullscreen <string>
                                 Leave fullscreen
      --key-leave-fullscreen <string>
                                 Leave fullscreen
      --global-key-play-pause <string>
                                 Play/Pause
      --key-play-pause <string>  Play/Pause
```

When I try to use them though, they don't work at all. I don't understand why do they have to take a `<string>` parameter as well.

So my scenario looks like this:

- I run VLC either with a UI or in headless mode
- I execute e.g. `vlc --key-next foo` (for triggering "next"), `foo` being a dummy parameter
- VLC doesn't complain (unlike when you don't pass a string), but command has no effect

**What's a working example of command-line-triggered VLC hot keys?**

Comment: Do you wanna bind them? Why you need this? If you want to bind them use global hotkeys https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_set_global_hotkeys/

Comment: You can control a large amount of vlc via dbus: see more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256193/linux-control-a-running-vlc-process-through-command-line#14256241

Answer (score 3):

By using `vlc --key-next foo` you've assigned "Next" to a key named "Foo", which you probably don't have. ;)

The `<string>` is composed of modifier keys (*Alt, Shift, Ctrl, Meta, Command*) separated by a dash (`-`) and terminated by a key (*a...z, +, =, -, ',', +, <, >, `, /, ;, ', \, [, ], *, Left, Right, Up, Down, Space, Enter, F1...F12, Home, End, Menu, Esc, Page Up, Page Down, Tab, Backspace, Mouse Wheel Up and Mouse Wheel Down*).

So `vlc --key-next alt-n` will set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to go to the Next media file loaded.

Alternatively `vlc --key-next "Page Down"` will set <kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

More info [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Hotkeys/).

Comment: Strictly speaking, I believe this answers my question. However, could you please tell me how to **trigger** a command such as *next*, rather than bind the command to a key?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to control the player like that (start, stop, pause, prev, next, etc.) via command-line arguments.

Comment: wiki.videolan.org/VLC-0-8-6_command-line_help It doesnt look like a way to control it live, just ways to start it up. Some of the scripting methods that people worked on, became obsolete in later versions. Talking to it with HTML? might stay longer, beings every thing is "web" these days :-)

Comment: Ahhh too bad. Given that VLC can run in single-instance mode (see terdon's answer) it should be feasible to communicate with the underlying running process behind the singleton instance. One can add files to its queue, so I was expecting that one could send it other kind of messages as well.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is almost certainly impossible. Command line arguments are passed to a program at launch. Once it has loaded, any settings changed will be in effect but you cannot pass any more arguments.

When you run `vlc --whatever` it will attempt to launch another instance of `vlc` which will load with the option `--whatever` set. If you have "allow only one instance" set in your `vlc` preferences, this will have no effect and it will look like "vlc does not complain". You *might* be able to get this sort of behavior from the [VideoLanServer](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html) but I have never used it and do not know. You will not get this from any "normal" program that is not running in some kind of server or listening mode.

[image]

A better question is *why* would you need this behavior? If you are displaying `vlc` output normally, you can just use the hotkeys normally as long as the vlc window has the mouse focus. Even if you don't and you are, for example, [watching vlc in a terminal](http://www.anilkarat.com/til/2010/12/09/vlc-watch-videos-in-ascii-art-even-without-x/) over an ssh connection to a headless server using its ASCII art output modes, the hotkeys work as long as the terminal with the `ssh` has focus. Are you trying to somehow script this behavior? Could this be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101)?

Comment: Yes I am using a single instance of VLC. I expected sending messages such as "play/pause" to those instances to be possible, since one can add additional items to a running instance from the command line.

Comment: Yes but what's the point of sending a hotkey at launch time? Do you want it to start paused? I don't understand what your desired behavior is. Why don't you just hit space when the video window has the focus?

Comment: No I don't want to send a hotkey at startup time. I want to send a message to running/existing instances: "stop the file you're playing".

Comment: I guess mine could be considered an XY question. I was attempting to build a music manager on top of VLC and sending messages sounded very tempting. Will look into a proper approach such as leveraging an API then.

Comment: If all you want is to pause/unpause a single vlc instance, you can do `kill -STOP $(pgrep vlc)` to pause and `kill -CONT $(pgrep vlc)` to unpause.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the case. Tnanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

terdon's comment is correct, with one small change.
As posted, the commands didn't work on my system (macOS) due to the problem of case.  If you add the -i flag to ignore case to the pgrep command, or capitalize the VLC argument, then the commands have the stated effect.

If all you want is to pause/unpause a single vlc instance, you can do `kill -STOP $(pgrep -i vlc)` to pause and `kill -CONT $(pgrep VLC)` to unpause.