# Using Hot keys with vlc's dummy interface

Tags: vlc-media-player, hotkeys

I would like to be able to use the hotkeys for vlc via the dummy interface in command line.
The [documentation](http://wiki.videolan.org/Interfaces) says it's possible, but I haven't found how to do it.

Thanks a lot for yours answers!

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/579002/using-vlcs-hot-keys-via-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

I found the answers :

In the terminal and using the dummy interface, this command don't wotk :

```
cvlc --key-next "ctrl-n" Music/
```

Meanwhile this one do work :

```
cvlc --global-key-next "ctrl-n" Music/
```

It took me a while to figure it out because my Alt key behave strangely.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the full list of available hotkey options by running:

```
$ cvlc --help
```

On my machine, I get a section like this:

```
 Hot keys
      --global-key-toggle-fullscreen <string>
                                 Fullscreen
      --key-toggle-fullscreen <string>
                                 Fullscreen
      --global-key-leave-fullscreen <string>
                                 Leave fullscreen
      --key-leave-fullscreen <string>
                                 Leave fullscreen
      --global-key-play-pause <string>
                                 Play/Pause
      --key-play-pause <string>  Play/Pause
      --global-key-faster <string>
                                 Faster
      --key-faster <string>      Faster
      --global-key-slower <string>
                                 Slower
      --key-slower <string>      Slower
      --global-key-rate-normal <string>
                                 Normal rate
      --key-rate-normal <string> Normal rate
      --global-key-rate-faster-fine <string>
                                 Faster (fine)
      --key-rate-faster-fine <string>
                                 Faster (fine)
      --global-key-rate-slower-fine <string>
                                 Slower (fine)
      --key-rate-slower-fine <string>
```

If you use any `global` hotkeys, that key combination will be unavailable to any other application.  If you use the non-global hotkeys, you'll have to enter them while the window containing the video has the focus (not the console).